# Not able to parse the json data jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to parse the JSON data like below in JavaScript...

```
    [{'cmodel':'FE73B','classification':'E6SLDD2','sbom':'{'BOMDetail': [{'MG': '11', 'RP': false, 
    'SF': '', 'SG': '010', 'Edt': '20180831', 'FVR': '', 'OPT': 'BLK', 'PNC': '01000A', 'Qty': '01', 
     'Rmk': '', 'SPN': false, 'Std': '20180301', 'cTy': '', 'FVPT': '', 'CFile': '', 'PSPtNo': '', 
   'PTSpec': '', 'PartNo': '4M42327401', 'PNCDesc': 'ENGINE ASSY', 'cReserveOR': 'S'}]}'}]
```

I need to parse the BOMDetail into an array to be looped...

Please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: that's not JSON (but pretty close). JSON requires double quotes (`"`) to represent keys and strings; your data uses single quotes instead (`'`), thus `JSON.parse()` fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
let arr = [{
'cmodel':'FE73B',
'classification':'E6SLDD2','sbom':"{'BOMDetail': [{'MG': '11', 'RP': false, 'SF': '', 'SG': '010', 'Edt': '20180831', 'FVR': '', 'OPT': 'BLK', 'PNC': '01000A', 'Qty': '01', 'Rmk':'', 'SPN':false, 'Std': '20180301', 'cTy': '', 'FVPT': '', 'CFile': '', 'PSPtNo': '', 'PTSpec': '', 'PartNo': '4M42327401', 'PNCDesc': 'ENGINE ASSY', 'cReserveOR': 'S'}]}"}] ;

let str = JSON.stringify(arr[0]);
let obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: I get an error like below...

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2

Comment: ..I need the json parsed into an array to be used in loop

Comment: I modify the answer, you can access the array by the index in a loop

Comment: i got the data from an api call like this

data=  [{'cmodel':'FE73B','classification':'E6SLDD2','sbom':'{'BOMDetail': [{'MG': '11', 'RP': false, 
    'SF': '', 'SG': '010', 'Edt': '20180831', 'FVR': '', 'OPT': 'BLK', 'PNC': '01000A', 'Qty': '01', 
     'Rmk': '', 'SPN': false, 'Std': '20180301', 'cTy': '', 'FVPT': '', 'CFile': '', 'PSPtNo': '', 
   'PTSpec': '', 'PartNo': '4M42327401', 'PNCDesc': 'ENGINE ASSY', 'cReserveOR': 'S'}]}'}]

and when i try to parse it into an array. like below..

var arr=[];
arr=json.parse(data[0]);

I get an error...it doesnt work

Comment: Try this, i modify the answer again